# How does RBS handles the versioning in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: rbs

How does RBS handles the versioning in SharePoint 2010? Does it mean that initial document alone will be stored on the file system and updates will be stored on the SQL? In that case, literally data is not delivered directly instead SQL handles the complete data delivery, correct? If so, what is the advantage we are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when versioning is enabled, a specific version you're adding will only be stored in RBS if its size is at least [MinimumBlobStorageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spremoteblobstoragesettings.minimumblobstoragesize%28v=office.15%29.aspx) bytes. Usually, this threshold is specified via PowerShell for a specific content database.

However, SharePoint is also smart enough that if you create a new version only as a result of metadata editing (e.g. you change item title), and the previous version is in RBS, it won't create a new blob in the RBS for this version, but will simply create a reference to the same blob.

What this means is that if you have an item with multiple versions, some versions may be stored in RBS and some in the content database.

Here's an example. You have a default RBS provider enabled and set `MinimumBlobStorageSize` threshold size to 100 KB. You're uploading pictures to a library that has versioning enabled.

- You upload picture.jpg (size: 30 KB). Because it's below the required RBS threhsold size, it gets stored in the content database.
- You upload picture.jpg (size: 400 KB). Beacuse it's over 100 KB, it gets stored in RBS.

Here's what things look like in the content database after these two steps:
[image]

As you can see, version 1 (513) has content stored in the database, while version 2 (1025) only keeps a blob reference (RbsId).

Now suppose you edit the title of the picture.jpg to NewPicture.jpg - an additional version is created:
[image]

Note that this newly-created version is still stored in the RBS, but no new blobs were created, saving space - RbsId used is the same for both versions, meaning that both versions point to the same blob in RBS. However, if you simply uploaded the same picture again as a new version, new RbsId would be assigned for this version and a new blob created - SharePoint won't detect that the data getting stored is duplicated.

(Note: I tested this with SharePoint 2010, but I assume the same holds true for 2013, though things may get a bit more complicated there due to shredded storage, where shreds can be shared between versions).

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Store data into Content Database, Documents are stored as Binary Large OBjects or BLOBs within the content database. Problem when you made actual change to file(15MB) sharepoint save a another copy of file with new version. that's fine but when you made changes to MetaData SharePoint again treat it new version stored another copy.

So in RBS, SharePoint **Content DB stored the Metadata** and all **blobs stored** into the **file system**.

Read this one. http://alberthoitingh.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/sharepoint-2010-and-remote-blob-storage-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK from my little RBS testing with StoragePoint, versioned files are still offloaded into the blob store. The SQL server keeps track of the pointers to each of the blob versions. SharePoint versioning is a straight copy, not a diff.

Comment: In general, this is not correct. Please see my answer for details.